# Чем является модель в приведённом коде?

Tags: javascript, java, mvc, spring-mvc, dom

В ходе изучения Spring MVC столкнулся с таким примером *(на листинге изображён метод rest-контроллера)*:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showAddUserForm(Model model) {

    User user = new User();
    model.addAttribute("userForm", user);
    //...
}
```

Метод принимает экземпляр некоего интерфейса `Model`. Меня смутило его название, потому что, насколько я понимаю, это не то же самое, что модель в MVC. Вот что написано в документации к этому интерфейсу:

> Специфичный для Java-5 интерфейс, определяющий держателя атрибутов
> модели. В первую очередь предназначен для добавления атрибутов в
> модель. Позволяет получить доступ к общей модели в виде java.util.Map.

Что это за общая модель? Насколько я понимаю, в эту `Model` добавляются какие-то атрибуты, а потом отправляются на UI, где `JS` их вытаскивает. Я примерно понимаю, как `Model` работает. Но не понимаю, что она такое.

Что из себя представлят эта Model? Чем она является в контексте `JavaScrypt`/`UI`/`DOM` или чего-то ещё? Что это такое и как оно выглядит вне rest-контроллеров Spring?

Comment: изучать паттерн MVC на примере spring mvc - не самый простой путь. в данном случае моделью является юзер. кусок кода, который вы привели - контроллер, а то, что у вас написано на джаваскрипте - вью. просто в спринговой реализаций это скорее mvp, чем mvc. я бы порекомендовал для начала изучать паттерны grasp, gof, а потом браться за архитектурные типа mvc, ибо в последнем между моделью и и вьюхой в каноническом виде должен быть гофовский  слушатель(но его тут нет в силу особенностей http-протокола), а контроллер - одноименный грасповский паттерн.

Answer (score 0):

Давайте попробую объяснить.

MVC - Шаблон проектирования предполагает разделение данных приложения, пользовательского интерфейса и управляющей логики на три отдельных компонента: Модель, Представление и Контроллер – таким образом, что модификация каждого компонента может осуществляться независимо.

В вашем случае дело происходит в контроллере в который приходит модель. Не заморачивайтесь слишком глубоко поскольку эта модель запроса в котором хранятся в виде Map параметры запроса. Добавив необходимых данных в этоту модель можно сгенерировать view и отправить ответом на запрос.